# How to format the output of a function when it is a list

Tags: r, list, function, format, output

I have a function `f` that returns a list `L` with different outputs. Let's suppose that the output is given by:

```
L[[1]] A vector of values
L[[2]] A matrix 
L[[3]] The result of a glm (or any regression model)
```

In order to facilitate the user the access to the information, I would like to give names

`(vector = L[[1]], matrix = L[[2]], fit = L[[3]])`

so that the user can write `L$vector`, `L$matrix` or `L$fit`.

How can I do this? I think the idea is similar to that used in `glm` because its output is a list but you can get the coefficients by `$coefficients`.

Thank you,

Comment: list(vector = L[[1]], matrix = L[[2]], fit = L[[3]])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign names for the list elements:

```
> L = list(values = "A vector of values",
+          matrix = matrix(1,3,3),
+          result = 1)
> L
$values
[1] "A vector of values"

$matrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1

$result
[1] 1
```

Then you can refer to the list elements with several ways, for example

```
> L[[3]]
[1] 1
> L$result
[1] 1
> L[['result']]
[1] 1
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't expect It was so easy. If I write `names(L)` I get the differewnt options (`vector`, `matrix` and `fit`) but when y write `L$` and I press TAB button, I don`t have the names. Any idea?

Comment: In RStudio, if you have defined `L` and then you write `L$`, you will see the names of the list elements as a pop-up list.

Comment: I have had to restart RStudio in some cases where the interface does not behave as expected. Could that help?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
result=list(vector=c(1,2,....), matrix=matrix, fit=model)
return(result)
```